# How to set primary key in the table that is generated using another table?

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following code to generate new table, same as that of another table, but the problem is that, the following script copies all the data but doesnt make the required column as primary key, where as in parent table it is primary key. Please guide how can i make the same column primary key as that of in parent table.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[c_temp1]
AS 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM dbo.sysobjects 
               WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[coil_temp1]') 
                 AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
       DROP TABLE [dbo].[coil_temp1]

    SELECT * 
    INTO coil_temp1 
    FROM coil
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This would create a copy of the primary key for you.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[c_temp1]
AS 

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @PrimaryColumns varchar(1000)
        ,@PimaryName varchar(255)
        ,@AddPrimaryKey varchar (1050)

IF EXISTS (SELECT   * 
           FROM     dbo.sysobjects 
           WHERE    id = object_id(N'[dbo].[coil_temp1]') 
                    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[coil_temp1]

select  @PrimaryColumns = coalesce(@PrimaryColumns + ',', '') +  COLUMN_NAME
from    (SELECT dISTINCT T1.CONSTRAINT_NAME , T2.COLUMN_NAME
        from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T1
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE T2
                ON T1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = T2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        where   T1.table_name = 'coil'
                AND T1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY')t3

SELECT  @PimaryName = T1.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T1
where   T1.table_name = 'coil'
        AND T1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

SELECT  * 
INTO    coil_temp1 
FROM    coil 

Set     @AddPrimaryKey = 'ALTER TABLE coil_temp1 ADD CONSTRAINT '+ @PimaryName +'_coil_temp1 PRIMARY KEY ('+@PrimaryColumns+')'

Exec (@AddPrimaryKey)

END
GO
```